# Buttons placed underneath each other with spaces

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 6 buttons which I would like to place underneath each other with spaces in between them but it seems to not be working.

this is my view:

```
   <div id="btnline1">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create","Purchase",null)" class="btn2">Create an Order</a>
</div>
      <div id="btnline2">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Purchase",null)" class="btn2">Mangage Orders</a>
     </div>

        <div id="btnline3">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Driver",null)" class="btn2">Manage Drivers </a>
        </div>

        <div id="btnline4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Equipment",null)" class="btn2">Manage Equipments</a>
        </div>
        <div id="btnline5">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Customer",null)" class="btn2">Manage Customers</a>
        </div>

        <div id="btnline6">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Report",null)" class="btn2">Reports</a>
        </div>
```

and this is my  css:

```
#btnline1,
#btnline2
#btnline3,
#btnline4,
#btnline5,
#btnline6
{
    float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;


}
```

here is an image of what it looks like:

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `#btnline2`:

```
#btnline1,
#btnline2
#btnline3,
```

Fix that, and add `clear: both` to the styles to force them to separate lines:

```
#btnline1,
#btnline2,
#btnline3,
#btnline4,
#btnline5,
#btnline6
{
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both;           //add this
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b1za7ta7/)